# "Intellisense" in emacs for clojure (inline docs & reminder drop-downs)?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, clojure, intellisense

In [this live-coding-in-clojure demo video](http://vimeo.com/22798433) of [Overtone](https://github.com/overtone/overtone), the author exhibits emacs flying through inline docs & reminder drop-downs. At 54 seconds in, he even emphasizes the fact, but doesn't drop the essential hint about how to enable it.

This is the one-big-missing thing in my otherwise-ideal emacs set-up (I use nrepl and leiningen) and the only thing that draws me to the otherwise-dreadful mouse-oriented tools like Intellij and Eclipse. I'm dying in need for this facility!

I don't have any idea what melpa packages to install to set this up, and I don't know what clever one-word name I would call it, so I don't know how to search for it. "Intellisense for Clojure in Emacs" is as close as I've been able to come to a search term, but it doesn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He is specifically using the [Overtone/emacs-live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) emacs setup, which contains all the configuration for what you see in the video. The auto complete and doc strings appear to be provided by the [`ac-nrepl`](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/ac-nrepl) package.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking about [`autocomplete.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete). Take a look and see if that isn't what you're referring to.